# How to grab all images from and section

Tags: templating, craft3

I am sure this must be answered somewhere and I cannot find it.  I need to grab all images from a section (**channel**) and display them in a slide show on the index page (index page is a **single**,so index page of the entries from that section). I just cannot seem to get this correct.  Here is what I am trying

```
 {% set storyItem = craft.entries.section('stories').find() %}
```

so stories is the section where the entries are.

Then

```
{% for previewImage in storyItem.slideshowImage.offset(1) %} 
 ...
{% for previewImage in storyItem.slideshowImage.limit(1) %} 
...
{% for previewImage in storyItem.slideshowImage.offset(1) %}
```

The limit and offset are just to make the slider I have work and that does work on another page so that does not seem to be what is stopping me here.  I am somewhat new to craft and my gut is telling me this is a simple answer but I have been stuck on it for a while now and coming back to it off and on to no avail.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this a Single section?  Otherwise, you want to grab every image from every field from every entry/entrytype in a section?

Comment: So the section I want to grab from is a channel (stories), and I am trying to display them on a single, which displays all entries for that channel further down the page.  I hope I am explaining that clearly,  I think what I am trying to do is the second part of you question, grab all from that section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to grab all images from a section and display them in a slide show on the index page.

You'll need to:

1. Loop through all of your story entries.
2. Grab the image from each story.
3. Compile those into a Twig array.
4. Create your slideshow as needed.

Here's how that all ties together...

```
{% set storyItems = craft.entries.section('stories').find() %}

{% set previewImages = [] %}

{% for item in storyItems %}
    {% set currentImage = item.slideshowImage.first() %}
    {% set previewImages = previewImages | merge(currentImage) %}
{% endfor %}

{# RENDER YOUR SLIDESHOW FROM previewImages #}
```

You'll need to initialize the `previewImages` array before beginning the `for` loop... Loops in Twig have their own scope.

> The limit and offset are just to make the slider I have work...

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do with the `offset`, but I'd recommend manipulating your images array in Twig (as opposed to fancy queries to target specific images).