# Get all images from a section

Tags: assets, filter, loop, assetfilemodel

I want to get all images from the section `projekte` which are bound to the asset field `bild` I then want to fiddle around with `.limit()` and maybe `random` filters.

So I grabbed all images like described [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12152/how-to-grab-all-images-from-and-section)

This works but as soon as I add `.limit()`

```
{% set projectImg = craft.entries.section('projekte').find() %}
{% set projectImages = [] %}

{% for item in projectImg %}
  {% set currentImage = item.bild %}
  {% set projectImages = projectImages | merge(currentImage) %}
{% endfor %}

{% for asset in projectImages.limit(3) %}
   <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

This results in

> PHP Notice: Array to string conversion

Why can't I just ad whatever filter I want on that new loop now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding of the difference between an ElementCriteria model and actual fetched elements.

Some useful background reading:

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel

[What are the differences between an elementCriteriaModel and fetched elements?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-are-the-differences-between-an-elementcriteriamodel-and-fetched-elements)

You could do what you're looking for using Twig's [random](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/random.html) method:

```
{% set projectImg = craft.entries.section('projekte').find() %}
{% set projectImages = [] %}

{% for item in projectImg %}
    {% set currentImage = item.bild %}
    {% set projectImages = projectImages | merge(currentImage) %}
{% endfor %}

{# Grab 3 random images from the array #}
{% for counter in 0..2 %}
    {% set asset = random(projectImages) %}

    <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```